# Search multiple columns

Tags: php

I have a user list of 100 or so users and I'm trying to create a search field so I can find a certain user easier. I would like to search by multiple columns in the user database.

I tried creating this query but I'm pretty new to this and I'm not sure about all the OR statements.

Here is what i got.

**My Search form:**

```
<form action="search-users.php" method="GET" class="no-margin">
<label>Type in a keyword to search for a user.</label><br><br>
<input type="text" name="keywords" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Example: John Doe"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Search Users">
</form>
```

**Then the action script:**

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['keywords'])){
        $keywords = escape($_GET['keywords']);

        $search = DB::getInstance()->query("
        SELECT `username`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`unit`,`email`,`rent_own`,`city`,`zip`,`phone` FROM `users` WHERE 
        `username`    LIKE '%{keywords}%' OR
        `first_name`  LIKE '%{keywords}%' OR
        `last_name`   LIKE '%{keywords}%' OR
        `unit`        LIKE '%{keywords}%' OR
        `email`       LIKE '%{keywords}%' OR
        `rent_own`    LIKE '%{keywords}%' OR
        `city`        LIKE '%{keywords}%' OR
        `zip`         LIKE '%{keywords}%' OR
        `phone`       LIKE '%{keywords}%'   
        ");

    }

    ?>

    <!--SHOW HOW MANY RESULT ARE RETURNED-->
    <h3 class="blue-tx" align="center">Found <?php echo $search->Count()?> results</h3>

    <?php

    if ($search->Count()){
        foreach($search->results() as $s){
            ?>
    ....Display user results here.
<?php } } ?>
```

If someone could guide me through this a little. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Where are your `$keywords` binded to query?

Comment: @ex3v I would get the keywords from the search form

Comment: You mistunderstood my question. You have variable `$keywords` containing some keywords from form. I get it. My question is - in which part of your code this variable is passed to query? How query "knows" that `%{keywords}%` fields must be filled with that variable?

Comment: Change `'%{keywords}%'` to `'%{$keywords}%'`

Comment: @ex3v I'm not sure, guess I better go figure that one out. When I write my queries the `DB::getInstance()->query` is a class and doesn't require me to bind or execute.

Comment: @Sal00m that got it working. Please write it as an answer and I will mark it as correct. Thank you!

Comment: My question was all about what @Sal00m posted ;) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `$` in keywords variable

Change:

'%{keywords}%' => '%{$keywords}%'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['keywords'])){
        $keywords = escape($_GET['keywords']);

        $search = DB::getInstance()->query("
        SELECT `username`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`unit`,`email`,`rent_own`,`city`,`zip`,`phone` FROM `users` WHERE 
        `username`    LIKE '%keywords%' OR
        `first_name`  LIKE '%keywords%' OR
        `last_name`   LIKE '%keywords%' OR
        `unit`        LIKE '%keywords%' OR
        `email`       LIKE '%keywords%' OR
        `rent_own`    LIKE '%keywords%' OR
        `city`        LIKE '%keywords%' OR
        `zip`         LIKE '%keywords%' OR
        `phone`       LIKE '%keywords%'   
        ");

    }

    ?>

    <!--SHOW HOW MANY RESULT ARE RETURNED-->
    <h3 class="blue-tx" align="center">Found <?php echo $search->Count()?> results</h3>

    <?php

    if ($search->Count()){
        foreach($search->results() as $s){
            ?>
    ....Display user results here.
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but did not work. Thanks for trying to help though. Changing `'%{keywords}%'` to `'%{$keywords}%'` did the trick.

Comment: I suggested Changing '%{keywords}%' to '%$keywords%'. 
And what error you are getting when you executed the same code in mysql server?